# Who designed the Disco Dingo wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

Seriously I didn't upgrade to 19.10 simply because I love Dingo's wallpaper so much that I didn't want to say goodbye.

With 20.04 coming up, and with Disco's batteries running out for the last time as its repos start failing, looks like my favourite Ubuntu wallpaper ever is reaching twilight. Goodbye Dear Friend.

Whoever did this design, IMO deserves a medal. The melding of animal and technical. The box back of the head reminiscent of a power supply, the subtly gaping mouth in ecstasy of the music..... the Cylon forehead.... the head tilted towards the stars...it was pure art.. with fuschia vectors.

Of course I could port Dingo to 20.04 but that would feel like an organ transplant. Better to let him vector through to the other side...

But I would like to know who designed him. Because you added a little something to my life, and you cemented my loyalty to Ubuntu. There was once a time when Apple owned this "we *get* Art" ethos. Ubuntu now arguably surpasses them.

[image]

Comment: You could just, you know, copy the wallpaper over.

Comment: @OrganicMarble as per the question "Of course I could port Dingo to 20.04 but that would feel like an organ transplant. Better to let him vector through to the other side..."

Comment: Wasn't sure what you meant by "porting".

Comment: You can install all prior wallpapers into later releases of Ubuntu, thus on a 19.10 release you can install 9.04 or 19.04 wallpapers (even for flavors by adding 'universe' repo)

Answer (score 4):

There was [a competition](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/wallpaper-competition-disco-dingo/9607/) for the wallpapers for 19.04 which went from January 2019 to March 2019. The default wallpaper appeared as [an entry](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/wallpaper-competition-disco-dingo/9607/70) from [zero-1729](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/u/zero-1729). The winners were [announced](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-community-wallpaper-competition-vote-here/10224/6) on 22 Mar 2019 and that wallpaper was among the winners. The winning wallpapers were added in [ubuntu-wallpapers-19.04.2-0ubuntu1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/19.04.2-0ubuntu1) which was uploaded by [Olivier Tilloy](https://launchpad.net/~osomon). You can see the publish history of all wallpaper packages on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/+publishinghistory).

**Opinion:**  I personally love the [blue variant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qckVf.jpg) which appeared in Ubuntu Studio. :)

Comment: Personally love the blue variante too. But unfortunately the link to zero-1729 is just a background backfill of the already-created dingo: https://twitter.com/ubuntu/status/1102608172311896064. Who designed the actual dingo vector art mascot?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne I thought you were concerned with wallpaper only. AFAIK macots are generally designed by the Ubuntu Artwork Team.